# How to detect small details in high resolution images using CNNs?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, keras

I have the goal of training a CNN model that can detect if clothing items has any defects (holes, stains etc.) on them. I am using Keras to accomplish this. I will use the model for image classification, there are five classes in total (clean, stain, hole, pethair, wrinkle).

To tell about the problem I am facing; the inputs I receive for inference will come from users, and they will be photos uploaded from these user's smartphones. So in average, input resolution will be 3024 x 4032 , and the aspect ratio will always be 3:4. I have collected a dataset of high resolution images, and set the input of my model to 900 x 1200 pixels. But still I can't seem to achieve any success when it comes to detecting small details, and my model's accuracy is pretty low. For example;

- [This the input image, 3024 x 4032 pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D35hE.jpg)
- [These are the holes I am trying to detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dH2X.png)

I think I have collected enough data to train the model, but I believe the details are lost when the images are resized to match the input resolution. What else can I do to make my model work? Is there any way other than setting the input resolution even higher?

Comment: Have you ever consider about NMF(non-negative matrix factorization)? Please take a look this [paper about NMF(Learning the parts of objects by non-negative matrix factorization)](https://www.nature.com/articles/44565). It could play roles of demension reduction method.

Comment: Could you specify what you do, image classification(there is/not) or object detection?

Comment: @RyuDaeSick I updated the post.

Comment: Do you want to detect if the images have certain defects or do some kind of image segmentation that finds the particular region of the image where the defect is? $//$ If you are doing the former, are you allowing for multiple defects to be in an image? (My laundry pile disputes any claim that only one can be present in a garment.)

Comment: @Dave I only want to detect if a garment is defected. So, the garment can have both stains and holes. However, for me the important thing is to tell the user that the garment is not in a perfect condition. So, if it has both a stain and a hole, it is enough to for me to get the model prediction with the highest score. I do not aim to locate the defects in the image.

Comment: @RyuDaeSick Thanks, I will try to implement it.